# Using if statement inside if statement, good or bad practice?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Is it OK to use **if** statement in this form, or should i need to use something else to get result. I want to get effect if filtration is on 100 % then check cX if is on 100 % to add sign-ok not before filtration is on 100 %.
Just need opinion is it a good coding or I should change the approach?

```
if (filtration === 100) {
    $(".filtration").removeClass('sign-no');
    $(".filtration").addClass('sign-ok');

    if (cX === 100){
        $(".cX").removeClass('sign-no');
        $(".cX").addClass('sign-ok');

        if (stripping === 100) {
            $(".stripping").removeClass('sign-no');
            $(".stripping").addClass('sign-ok');

            if (precipitation === 100) {
                $(".precipitation").removeClass('sign-no');
                $(".precipitation").addClass('sign-ok');
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Does it express what you want? Then yes, it's fine. Might there be a better way to write this? Possibly yes.

Comment: And where are `filtration`, `cX`, `stripping`, `precipitation` defined? Understanding those variables a little more might lead to a better method

Comment: Yes it is, just didn't know is it OK to code this way. Thanks.

Comment: @NewToJS values for the variables are from google sheet, the maximum value is 100% and minimum is 0.

Comment: If 'sign-no' and 'sign-ok' are always mutually exclusive, you may want to consider `toggleClass` with a single class name.

Comment: you could check for not equal and return early.

Comment: Was gonna write an answer but this got put on hold. I would do it with early return style by wrapping the code in a function, see here: https://jsfiddle.net/0yyy3jac/

Comment: Thank You all for Your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No issues. You can use. But if only first condition is true, then second condition will be checked and if it is true only it check the third condition and likewise.

Comment: Thanks for Your help.

Comment: at anytime! @Blackness

Comment: If it solves your problem, try marking as answer.  @Blackness

Answer (score 1):

Its okay, you can do it. But if you set a value on code quality, you should use maximal 2 depth in a block.

Must Code Quality Tools has a configuration for it.

- [ESLint](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/max-depth)
- [JSLint](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#maxdepth)
- ....